# Chebyshev's Inequality given mean and variance

Tags: probability, random-variables

Give examples of random variables Y with mean 0 and variance 1
such that

(a) $P(|Y | ≥ 2) = \frac{1}{4}$

(b) $P(|Y | ≥ 2) < \frac{1}{4}$

I know Chebyshev's equality must be used here but I am struggling with how to think of examples that fit the given restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is the equality case in Chebyshev's inequality, and that's very tightly constrained. The variable must be supported on exactly three points: the mean, the point we're measuring at, and its reflection on the opposite side. That's $\{-2,0,2\}$ here.

So, what should the probabilities be to match the mean and variance? For the mean, we must have $P(-2)=P(2)$. For the variance, we must have $4\cdot P(-2)+0\cdot P(0)+4\cdot P(2)=1$, and $P(-2)+P(2)=2P(2)=\frac14$. Since the total probability is $1$, that's a probability mass function $P(-2)=\frac18$, $P(0)=\frac34$, $P(2)=\frac18$.

The second? Take absolutely any other distribution with the desired mean and variance.

Can't think of one? Whatever your favorite random variable $X$ is, if it has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, $Y=(X-\mu)/\sigma$ has mean zero and variance $1$.

Comment: If I take X to be a random variable that is either -1 or 1 each with probability 1/2 (this RV has mean 0 and variance 1), then Y also satisfies the condition?

Comment: Yes. The probability of it being $\ge 2$ in absolute value is zero, after all.